# centOS on a flashdrive

Tags: centos

I am considering installing `centOS` to a flash drive, using `command line` only.

I plan on using `centOS` to become familiar with `Redhat` and get better at utilizing it as a system admin.

What is a suitable sized flashdrive I should use for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 8GB flashdrive should be suitable for a basic install of CentOS 5 or CentOS 6. If you take a look at this page maintained by the CentOS project it has all the minimum/maximum numbers that you need to concern yourself with when installing it.

- http://wiki.centos.org/About/Product

[image: ss $1]

Looking at the chart for either 5 or 6 you'll want a minimum of 1GB of storage to start. However I would suggest, still 8GB, especially if you're planning on running any GUI's or desktop envrionments from this.

Comment: No i just plan on using command line